# Online Java GUI Builder? At least Layout Manager

Tags: java, layout-manager

I cannot find one online and I am surprised there isn't one... but is there an online Java GUI Layoutmanager at least?

Comment: You mean a drag-n-drop swing GUI builder that will emit Java source code that you can then download and import into your favorite IDE? Sounds like a fun project for you to start ;-)

Comment: GUI builders are a bad idea in the first place (for anything but prototyping).  A net based GUI builder raises the bar.  But since I'm here, there is a little [`GridBagLayout` Tester](http://rabbitbrush.frazmtn.com/gridbagtester.html) available (not quite what you were asking, but similar).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) for Eclipse is phenomenal. One of the things that awesome about it is that you can hand modify its' generated code and it will pick that up without a problem.

What do you mean by an online GUI builder? If you want one that's a webapp, it's not likely you're going to find one.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a GUI to build a GUI, I would recommend the Netbeans IDE. I forget where it is exactly in the IDE, but you can basically just do file->new->java-gui (or something of the sort) and you will get a very nice interface for constructing swing gui's.

Comment: as Jeremy said, it emits source code as you construct the gui into a file, so you can write your own code to handle events like when a button is clicked.